# Neo4j chyper game of thrones

Tags: neo4j

I have a question. So I was visiting this site and I am learning neo4j, and I have a question about this clause:
(this is the site: [game of thrones site](http://www.lyonwj.com/2016/06/26/graph-of-thrones-neo4j-social-network-analysis/))

```
    MATCH (c:Character)-[r:INTERACTS]-()
RETURN c.name AS character, sum(r.weight) AS weightedDegree ORDER BY weightedDegree DESC
```

This clause is something similar to what I would like to find out. I am trying to find the average weight of the characters. I have tried something like this:

```
MATCH (c:Character)-[r:INTERACTS]-()
MATCH (n)
WITH n=sum(r.weight) AS ses
RETURN c.name AS character, avg(ses) AS weightedDegree ORDER BY weightedDegree DESC
```

but it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are looking for. Here are two possible answers:

1. To find the average `weightedDegree` value (across all characters):

   ```
   MATCH (c:Character)-[r:INTERACTS]-()
   WITH c, SUM(r.weight) AS weightedDegree
   RETURN AVG(weightedDegree) AS averageWeightedDegree;
   ```
2. To find the average `INTERACTS` weight for each character, in descending average weight order, limited to the 5 characters with the highest average:

   ```
   MATCH (c:Character)-[r:INTERACTS]-()
   RETURN c.name AS character, AVG(r.weight) AS avgWeight
   ORDER BY avgWeight DESC
   LIMIT 5;
   ```

Comment: Do you mind sharing how I would show the first 5 characters that have the biggest average weighted degree? Something with limit ascend?

Comment: the second option you gave is the one I was looking for, now I can just change DESC with ASC and get the biggest values, thank you